# How to DRY based on convention this bit of Ninject code

Tags: c#, ninject, dry

I have the following binding code

```
 Kernel
     .Bind<IWeinCadDocument>()
     .To<ADocument>().Named(ADocument._TypeId_.ToString());
 Kernel
     .Bind<IWeinCadDocument>()
     .To<BDocument>().Named(BDocument._TypeId_.ToString());
 Kernel
     .Bind<IWeinCadDocument>()
     .To<CDocument>().Named(CDocument._TypeId_.ToString());
```

The idea is that some data will be serialized with the TypeId of the container that needs to be constructed to house it. Each class has a static field **Guid _TypeId_**. This means I can get a new document of the correct type via Guid;

```
Guid id = data.TypeId;
var container = Kernel.Get<IWeinCadDocument>(id);
container.SetData(data);
```

I have many many IWeinCadDocument types and I'd like to DRY the binding code so I don't have to copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an *TypeID* field to my class I can just hijack the GuidAttribute used for COM interop. For example

```
[Guid("4882176A-751A-4153-928A-915BEA87FAB3")]
public class ADocument : WeinCadDocumentBase<ADocument>
{
    public ADocument( IWeinCadDocumentStorage storage )
        : base(storage)
    {
    }
     public override object PersistentData
    {
        get
        {
            return new DocumentData(10, 20);
        }
    }
 }
```

and

```
var documentTypes = new[]
    {
        typeof (ADocument), typeof (BDocument), typeof (CDocument)
    };

foreach (var documentType in documentTypes)
{
    Kernel.Bind<IWeinCadDocument>()
          .To(documentType)
          .Named(documentType.GUID.ToString());
}
```

I could wrap the above code in an extension method if I choose but the loop is the key.